# Adding module to existing Qt5 installation from source

Tags: qt

I have an existing Qt5.3.2 installation from tar.gz source files.

When attempting to compile VTK, which has optional Qt{4,5} interface, I was informed I don't have QtWebKitWidgets by ccmake.

I don't particularly want to reinstall Qt5 on top of the existing installation, for fear of breaking other things built against it.

Can I add to my current Qt5?

Would variants on

```
/path/to/configure -release -prefix $existingPrefix
make -module-qtwebkit
make install
```

or

```
/path/to/configure -release -prefix $newPrefix
make -module-qtwebkit
make install
cp -rf $newPrefix/CMake/QtWebKit (or similar path) $existingPrefix/CMake/
```

or as above, but with symlink, work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt5.3 no longer includes QtWebKit, which should now be built separately.

The WebKit package can be downloaded from the Qt Downloads website, via the separate packages repository: [link for 5.3.2](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.2/submodules/)

This can then be installed by appropriately setting environment variables such that the relevant (Qt5.3.2) qmake is first in the path, then from the expanded source directory, typing:

```
qmake
make -jN (with N make jobs)
(sudo, if appropriate) make install
```

The download is approximately 50MB.

Edit: It's also worth noting that if your Bison version is 3.x, then you might not be able to build the snapshot for QtWebKit. Instead download from the [development repositories](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtwebkit), to avoid an error looking something like: [link to bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32913)

```
g++ -c [...] -o .obj/release-shared/generated/glslang_tab.o generated/glslang_tab.cpp
generated/glslang_tab.cpp: In function 'int yyparse(TParseContext*)':
generated/glslang_tab.cpp:1785:30: error: too few arguments to function 'int yylex(YYSTYPE*, void*)'
yychar = yylex (&yylval);
^
generated/glslang_tab.cpp:279:12: note: declared here
extern int yylex(YYSTYPE* yylval_param, void* yyscanner);
```